# onkeyup (function) not registering

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, validation

I am trying to validate a form. I'm doing this by creating a JS code that ensures all text fields have atleast a character in it and if not the submit button is disabled. However, when i run this code my submit button becomes active after filling out only one field.

Also if you find any bugs etc please point them out, cheers.

This is my HTML

```
<form name = "form" onsubmit="validate()">
        <h3>Please complete the form below. Mandatory fields marked with *</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <h4>Personal Details</h4>
            <p>
           <label for="fname">*First Name</label> <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form"  >
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="lname">*Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form" />
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="Etype">Gender</label>
                <select class = "form" id="gender" name="gender"><option value="">Select...</option>

                    <option value="male">Male</option>

                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p>
            <label for="age">*Age</label>
                <select class = "form" id="age" name="age"><option value="">Select...</option>

                    <option value="youngest">3-7</option>

                    <option value="young">7-12</option>

                    <option value="teen">12-16</option>

                    <option value="young-adult">16-18</option>

                    <option value="adult">18+</option>

                </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label for="s_add">*Street Address</label> <input type="text" name="s_add" id="s_add" placeholder="Insert Street Address" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form" />
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="s_sub">*Suburb</label> <input type="text" name="s_sub" id="s_sub" placeholder="Suburb" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="state">*State</label> <input type="text" name="state" id="state" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form" />
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="pcode">*Postcode</label> <input type="text" name="pcode" id="pcode" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form" />
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="phone">*Phone</label> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Mobile or Home" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="email">*Email</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form"/>
                </p>

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <h4>Emergency Contact</h4>
                <p> please select someone within a close vicinity of 'Clowning Around'. </p>
                <p>
                <label for="fname">*First Name</label> <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onKeyup="validate()" placeholder="First Name" class = "form" /> 
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>
                <label for="lname">*Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form" />
                </p>
                <br>
                 <p>
                <label for="s_add"> *Street Address</label> <input type="text" name="s_add" id="s_add" placeholder="Insert Street Address" onKeyup="validate()" class = "form" />
                </p>
                <br>
                  <p>
                <label for="Mnum"> *Mobile Number</label> <input type="text" name="Mnum" id="Mnum" placeholder="Mobile Number" class = "form" />
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>
                <label for="Relationship"> *Relationship</label> <input placeholder="E.g Parent" class = "form"/>
               </p>
               <br>
               <p>
            <input id="SubmitButton" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <h4> Type of Enrollment </h4>
        <label for="Etype">*What would you like to enrol in?</label>
                <select class = "form" id="Etype" name="Etype"><option value="">Select...</option>

                    <option value="Camp">Camp</option>

                    <option value="Class">Class</option>
                </select>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</fieldset>
```

as you can see in my code ive added onKeyup="validate()" in the inputs.

This is my JS

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("The window has finished loading");


    var SubmitButton = document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
    SubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("The submit button has been clicked");}, false);

    var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
    fname.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    console.log((fname).value);}, false);

    var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
    lname.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    console.log((lname).value);
    validate();}, false);
}

function validate() 

     {
        var x = document.forms["form"].elements;
        var xbutton = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < xbutton.length; i++) {
            if (x[i].value.length == 0) xbutton = false;
        }

        if (xbutton) {
             document.getElementById('SubmitButton').disabled = !xbutton;
        }
    }
```

I've added the first function just in case its related.

Edit: 
I've fixed var i = 0; i < xbutton.length; i++
to x.length

Now when i run the code i get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

for line if `(x[i].value.length == 0) xbutton = false;`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop isn't right, you refer to `xbutton.length` but it should be `x.length` because `x` is the list of elements and `xbutton` is a boolean:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
```

Also, you're duplicating the event handlers by using both the inline `onkeyup` and `addEventListener`. Use one or the other.

Finally, in the `onsubmit` handler, you need to `return false` in order to prevent the form from submitting, if the validation fails.

---

The new error occurs because you have `fieldset` elements included in the `form.elements` list, so you're trying to get the `value` of a fieldset which doesn't exist. To resolve that, add a condition to check that the element is an `input[type=text]`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].tagName == 'INPUT' && x[i].type == 'text'){
        if (x[i].value.length == 0) xbutton = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've replaced xbutton.length with x.length however now when i look at my console this error appears

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined this is in relation to this line

 if (x[i].value.length == 0) xbutton = false;